# React Native Error : could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I am encountering the following error after adding useDispatch(). Although I have wrapped the App component with Provider, the issue remains unresolved. To run the app on my phone, I am using the Expo Go app and running the command **npm start**.

ERROR  Error: **could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a**

This error is located at:
in Products (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ScrollView)
in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

---

**constant.js->**

```
export const Add_to_Cart = "add_to_cart";
```

**action.js->**

```
import { Add_to_Cart } from "./constant";

export function AddToCartfunction(item)
{
    return{
        type: Add_to_Cart,
        data:item
    }

}
```

**reducer.js->**

```
import { Add_to_Cart } from "./constant";

const initState = [];

export const reducer = (state = initState, action)=>{

    switch(action.type)
    {
        case Add_to_Cart:
            return [ ...state, action.data ]
        default:
            return state
   }
}
```

**rootReducer.js->**

```
import { reducer } from "./reducer";
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

export default combineReducers({reducer});
```

**store.js ->**

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import rootreducer from './rootreducer'

const store = configureStore({reducer:rootreducer});
export default store;
```

**index.js->**

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./Components/store";


const AppWraper = ()=>
(
    <Provider store = {store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
)
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName,()=>AppWraper);
```

**App.js->**

```
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView,} from "react-native";
import Header from "./Components/header";
import Products from "./Components/products";

export default function App() {


  const products = [
    {
      name: "Realme 7",
      price: 13000,
      color: "Bluegrey",
      url: "https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-icon-mobile-phone-695.png",
    },
    {
      name: "Poco X3",
      price: 16000,
      color: "Blue",
      url: "https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-icon-mobile-phone-695.png",
    },
    {
      name: "Redmi Note 10",
      price: 12000,
      color: "Black",
      url: "https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-icon-mobile-phone-695.png",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
     
<ScrollView>
      {products.map((item) => <Products  item={item}/>)}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { marginTop: 38, flex: 1 },
});
```

**header.js->**

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="dark" backgroundColor="#e0b72f" />
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>0</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingRight: 25,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    backgroundColor: "#e0b72f",
    borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
  },
});
```

**products.js ->**

```
import { StyleSheet, View,Text,Image,Button,Pressable } from "react-native";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { AddToCartfunction } from "./action";


export default function Products(props) {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const AToCart = (item)=>{
dispatch(AddToCartfunction(item))
  }
 
  return (
    
    <View key={props.item.name} style={{alignItems: "center", borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#eee",  margin: 10,
            padding: 20, elevation: 2, shadowColor: "#644f0b",  }} >

          <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>{props.item.name}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>₹{props.item.price}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>{props.item.color}</Text>
          <Image
            style={{ height: 100, width: 100 ,marginVertical:10}}
            source={{ uri: props.item.url }}
          />
         
          <Pressable onPress={()=>AToCart(props.item)}> 
            <View style={styles.pressablebutton}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "black", fontWeight:500 }}>Add to Cart</Text>
            </View>
          </Pressable>

        </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { margin:20},
  pressablebutton: {
    backgroundColor: "#e0b72f",
    elevation: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },

});
```

Comment: Well, it certainly appears that there is a provided Redux store to the app. Think you could create a ***running*** [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?